# Clipboard manager with ability exclude applications

Tags: windows, clipboard

I'm looking for a Windows clipboard manager (but if it is cross-platform it would be nice) similar to ClipX and working on Windows 7 and up.

The app should have several obligate features (in order of importance):

1. Ability to exclude applications from which you are copying to a clipboard: I don't want to write in clipboard history passwords and logins from e.g. KeePass or any other password keeper.
2. Logging clipboard history to a file (like ClipX plugin DiskLog).
3. Changeable hotkeys.
4. Should be ligthweight.

Comment: maybe explain why *ClipX* does not fit your needs...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy, ClipX doesn't work properly on Windows 7 and up - it's often freeze and memory leak and not supported since 2008 year. On windows 10 it's working unstable and crash from time to time. Also it doesn't have ability to exclude applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArsClip works well and is highly configurable.  You can exclude apps like KeePass and 1Password, but since LastPass is an extension, you would have to exclude the web browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) for it to work there.

It has programmable key-mappings and is also very lightweight and portable (5MB .exe).

http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/

Comment: Thanks! This application is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Clipboard Magic](https://www.cybermatrix.com/clipboard-magic.html) could be useful.

1. Unfortunately you can't exclude apps you select, but you can temporarily disable clipboard monitoring.
2. You can save recorded clips to a file.
3. There's possibility to change hotkeys.
4. Yes, Clipboard Magic is simple and small.

Main Clipboard Magic's window:
[image: main window]

Settings screen:
[image: settings screen]